# VS 2015- typescript does not generate javascript files

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, typescript, visual-studio-2015

I just installed VS 2015 Community.
After building no js files are created inside the solution or the explorer.

Comment: Use [traceur](https://github.com/google/traceur-compiler), there may be some plugin/package available for VS

Comment: You are sure you just haven't forgot to show hidden files in solution explorer?

Comment: @NicklasWinger I tryied that too.

Comment: Are you using Typescript 1.6 or 1.5?

Comment: @StavAlfi are you using a tsconfig.json file?  Have you tried running a sample project (.sln) to confirm VS2015 is working?  Can you put your project files on github?

Here's a sample project I created for VS2015 + TypeScript + Cordova. If it works, then there's no problem with VS2015 [https://github.com/dbiele/TypeScript-Cordova-SystemJS](https://github.com/dbiele/TypeScript-Cordova-SystemJS)

Comment: @DeanB_Develop I added to your project typescript file in the WWW folder. Where can I find the JS file so I can use it in my project? (Im very begginer in typescript)

Comment: @StavAlfi  Channel9.msdn.com has some really good intro videos on using VS2015 Community + typescript.  Here are a few
[https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/ConnectOn-Demand/Introducing-Visual-Studio-Community-2015](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/ConnectOn-Demand/Introducing-Visual-Studio-Community-2015)  [https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Visual-Studio-Tools-for-Apache-Cordova/Using-Karma-and-Jasmine-To-Test-Apache-Cordova-Apps-in-Visual-Studio-2015](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Visual-Studio-Tools-for-Apache-Cordova/Using-Karma-and-Jasmine-To-Test-Apache-Cordova-Apps-in-Visual-Studio-2015)

Comment: @StavAlfi Here are some pointers when looking at the sample github I sent you.  Note: This is for a TypeScript Cordova Project. `./script` folder is where .ts and d.ts files are located.  When building (ex. Debug > Android > Ripple) VS2015 compiles the .ts file to .js and places them in the `./www` folder.  `./scripts/tsconfig.json` handles the exporting. package.json = npm package manager. gulpfile.js = task runner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to thanks all who tryied to help But the solution in cordova typescript project - **The compiled .ts files are inside the www\scripts\appBundle.js.**

*you may need to use @Micheal Braude solution to see the appBundle.js file.

thanks agian.

Comment: You didn't mention this was a Cordova project :) This file is configurable. You can change the "out" property in tsconfig.json to rename this to anything you want.

Answer (score 5):

TypeScript is part of Community. The produced .js files aren't part of the project, so you won't see them unless you turn on 'show all files' from the solution explorer. Here is the button you need to press:

[image]

Then the .js files will appear after you build:

[image]

If you're not seeing these, then check to make sure you're using this project template:

[image]

Comment: The compiled .ts files are inside the www\scripts\appBundle.js. thanks very much anyway. im sure it will help for alot others.

Comment: FFS! Your answer helped me. Thought I was going mad :|

Answer (score 0):

I`m not sure that VS 2015 Enterprise works like Community version, but I tried to explain you, how to  create *Simple TypeScript* project, and configure it for using step by step.

### Steps

1. Create new ***HTML Application, developed for TypeScript***.
   When you have done it, you would get something like on image below:
   [image]
   It is a simple structure of application, here we have file *app.ts*, *html* view, and *css* style-sheet.
2. Configure compilation - What you should to know about this step:

   - ES target version
   - Compile single merged file or separate files.

   Enter project configurations -->> Open TypeScripts Compilation tab -->> 
   Choose required ES version in ComboBox -->> Write path to compiled file and it name, if needed (located slightly below).
3. Add your first file to solution and write some code in it
4. Create your file.

   4.1. If you prefer *separate compilation* then you should add dependency for your js file into html view. Usually, the *.js file compiled in the same location folder of *.ts file, that`s why targeting on you `ts` file when write dependency to `js` file

   4.2. If you prefer merged compilation, first that you need - it is configure order of file, it is very simple challenge:
   Add into the main file (in my case usually it is `app.ts`) and write in it list of your dependencies

   ```
   ///<reference path="path/to/file1.ts"/>
   ///<reference path="path/to/file2.ts"/>
   ```

   Than, you should replace in *html view* this default script path:
       
   with path to **your final js file**
5. Test your application:

   - try to add some code that would help you to be ensure that your code works perfectly
   - run you application and ensure that it works as you expected.

Good Luck! I hope that this post helps you in your beginnings!!

### P.S. [Here](https://github.com/OlegDokuka/Confused-about-TypeScript-modules) working project.

Comment: The compiled .ts files are inside the www\scripts\appBundle.js. thanks very much anyway. im sure it will help for alot others.